# How does Spring-JPA EntityManager handle "broken" connections?

Tags: spring, jpa, entitymanager

I have an application that uses a Spring-EntityManager (JPA) and I wonder what happens if the database happens to be unavailable during the lifetime of my aforesaid application.

I expect in that situation it will throw an exception the first time to do anything on the database, right?

But, say I wait 10 minutes and try again then and the DB happens to be back. Will it recover? Can I arrange it so it does?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, neither Spring nor JPA have anything to do with it. Internally all persistence frameworks simply call [`DataSource.getConnection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection()) and expect to receive (probably pooled) JDBC connection. Once they're done, they `close()` the connection effectively returning it to the pool.

Now when the `DataSource` is asked to give a connection but database is unaivalable it will throw an exception. That exception will propagate up and will be somehow handled by whatever framework you use.

Now to answer your question - typically `DataSource` implementation (like [dbcp](/questions/tagged/dbcp), [c3p0](/questions/tagged/c3p0), etc.) will discard connection known to be broken and replace it with a fresh one. It really depends on the provider, but you can safely assume that once the database is available again, the `DataSource` will gradually get rid of *sick* connections and replace them with *healthy* ones.

Also many `DataSource` implementors provide ways of testing the connection periodically and before it is returned to the client. This is important in pooled environemnts where the `DataSource` contains a pool of connections and when the database becomes unavailable it has no way to discover that. So some `DataSource`s test connection (by calling `SELECT 1` or similar) before giving it back to the client and do the same once in a while to get rid of broken connections, e.g. due to broken underlying TCP connection.

## TL;DR

**Yes**, you will get an exception and **yes** the system will work normally once the database is back. BTW you can easily test this!