# Test is SessionFactory is valid

Tags: java, hibernate, testing, tdd

I tried to test if SessionFactory was valid through:

```
assertFalse(sessionFactory.isClosed());
```

But my test passes even if the underlaying datasource could not get connections:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
```

How can I test if the SessionFactory is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you really want to test whether you have valid database connectivity. `SessionFactory` is just a wrapper, once configured it will work as long as underlying `DataSource` is fine.

So how do you test `DataSource`? First of all various connection pools allow you to define so-called *test query*. Typically `"SELECT 1"`. If your database connection pool does not expose such a functionality, just pick any connection from your pool and run similar query.

## See also

- [How does Spring-JPA EntityManager handle "broken" connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481644)
- [How to get jdbc connection from hibernate session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482731)

Comment: Great! I went for the testing the connection directly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is what my test code looks like after [@Tomasz Nurkievicz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605744/tomasz-nurkiewicz) answer:

```
@Test(description = "Test we can get the connection factory")
public void getApplicationSessionFactory() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    Session session = null;
    try {
        sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.doWork(new Work() {
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            assertFalse(connection.isClosed());
        }
        });
    } finally {
        if ( session != null ) {
            session.close();
        }
        if (sessionFactory != null) {
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
    }
}
```